# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. when trying to scrape a file from the internet

Tags: .net, ssl

Get the error message:

```
"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
even after adding the tls protocols
The server is using TLS1.2
Am using dotnet 4.5.2 framework for building the application
Even a normal request is failing
```

Code snippet:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("httlps://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

This was working earlier but stopped working recently.

Comment: This site is currently down. I cannot even access it from a web browser. Even a simple TCP connection will not work. So it is not specific to this application.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running this on? TLS1.2 may not be enabled by default.

Comment: SSL Labs says the site [only supports TLS1.2 (see Configuration section)](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=docs.legis.wisconsin.gov) but if your version of Windows doesn't (possibly not enabled) then you won't be able to connect. It may be that they have recently disabled previous versions of TLS which is why it has recently stopped working.

Comment: Weird, I can't browse the site even though SSL Labs must have been able to connect